Tool that will push notifications to all of my Apple devices?
I'm on the Apple ecosystem; I use a Mac, iPhone, and Watch. Apple has designed their notifications so a notification will generally appear on only one device, but not all.
This is a problem for me. I sometimes fail to notice that a meeting/event is about to occur because the ecosystem wrongly assumes that I saw the notification that it sent to just one of the devices. I could benefit from seeing notifications everywhere.

This SE post on the Apple-related site describes my predicament.
This Apple page describes the "feature" between iOS and WatchOS.
This Apple page says that the one-device-only behavior is normal.

Does anyone know of an third-party app/service that will address this otherwise-normal behavior, and push calendar notifications to all of my Apple devices?
(I'm also open to hearing about any other hacks or ideas in the comments.)
